# How to listen to microphone input in real time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to listen to the microphone input while it is recording. I've been searching for a while but nothing really relevant comes up. Is this supported by the  SDK or is it a bit of a hack to set up?

I've found this but I'd like to find something a little more educational.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is supported, the framework is called Audio Sessions, the SDK guide is called "Audio Session Programming Guide", AudioSessionInitialize is probably a good starting point to learn the process.

I think there are a few decent example projects, aurioTouch I believe has some of the pieces you need.